# How to set border between two products in css?

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code:

```
 <div id="featured-products">
    <h3 class="text-center">Our Products</h3>
    <div class="grid-uniform">
       <div class='row'>
          <div class='clear'></div>
          <div class="product first">
             <div class="grid-item large--col-4 medium-down--col-4">
                <a href="/collections/frontpage/products/copy-of-test">
                <img src="img/pro-1.png" alt="Copy of Test">
                </a>
                <!-- .coll-image-wrap -->
                <div class="coll-prod-caption">
                   <a class="coll-prod-buy styled-small-button" href="/collections/frontpage/products/copy-of-test">
                   Buy
                   </a>
                   <div class="coll-prod-meta ">
                      <h5><a href="/collections/frontpage/products/copy-of-test">Express</a></h5>
                      <p class="coll-prod-price accent-text">
                         $.79.00
                      </p>
                   </div>
                   <!-- .coll-prod-meta -->
                </div>
             </div>
             <!-- .coll-prod-caption -->
          </div>
          <div class="product second">
             <div class="grid-item large--col-4 medium-down--col-4">
                <a href="/collections/frontpage/products/test">
                <img src="img/pro-1.png" alt="Test">
                </a>
                <!-- .coll-image-wrap -->
                <div class="coll-prod-caption">
                   <a class="coll-prod-buy styled-small-button" href="/collections/frontpage/products/test">
                   Buy
                   </a>
                   <div class="coll-prod-meta ">
                      <h5><a href="/collections/frontpage/products/test">Full</a></h5>
                      <p class="coll-prod-price accent-text">
                         $.79.00
                      </p>
                   </div>
                   <!-- .coll-prod-meta -->
                </div>
                <!-- .coll-prod-caption -->
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brs0kr6q/

Now my page look like this http://s3.postimg.org/9akuidnf7/Untitled_2.png

I need add border around each product like this http://s30.postimg.org/424hmkpoh/products.jpg

For that, when i add border, something not aligned properly. I think in my existing css code will be override the styles.

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: thanks for all answers :)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you need is ".product > .grid-item", so the border is applied to .grid-items that are child of .product but not to others .grid-items.

```
.product > .grid-item {border:1px solid #ddd... }
```

Check this: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pattern-matching

...change border, padding, margin, etc as needed, with selectors with more specificity http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity . I guess something like:

```
.product > .grid-item {
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 margin-left: 40px;
 padding-left: 0;
}
.product > .grid-item > .coll-prod-caption {margin-bottom:0}
```

...produce your wanted results.

Comment: Thanks @miguel-svq... but didn't align price section properly.. http://s27.postimg.org/c3hza5pmb/Untitled_1.png

Comment: Same thing, created a more specific selector to do this just inside .product (not afecting other .grid-item ) .product > grid-item coll-prod-meta p,  .product > grid-item coll-prod-meta h5 {display inline-block; float:left ...or whatever... }

Answer (score 0):

On your link image: add a class (eg: bordered)

```
<a href="/collections/frontpage/products/test" class="bordered">
                <img src="img/pro-1.png" alt="Test">
                </a>
```

And CSS:

```
a.bordered {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
border: solid 1px #dddddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this following `CSS`:

```
.grid-item a{
   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
   display: block;
}
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/brs0kr6q/3/)

Comment: my condition is that, should not change any grid-item selector, because it will be affected another section in my webpage. thanks @manwal.. i need add styles only in .product class...

Comment: so that i added styles for .product like this float: left;
list-style: outside none none;
display: block;
border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
margin-left: 61px; .. but little bit have to be change.. now look like this http://s30.postimg.org/80b1xp3wh/Untitled_1.png

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
.grid-item {
    border:solid;
    padding-left:0;
}

.product {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

the result you see in the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/brs0kr6q/2/

if you want exactly the same as the picture you posted you need to update the class `.coll-prod-caption` remove the margin from there

EDIT:
Working with selectors:

http://jsfiddle.net/brs0kr6q/5/

you write product instead of first, i have do that only for you that you get a feeling how selectors will work

Comment: my condition is that, should not change any grid-item selector, because it will be affected another section in my webpage..

Comment: have you the possibility to add another class to this div?

Comment: If i add another class.. i could be avoid .grid-item styles.. but i need .grid-item styles @manu .. thanks

Comment: where is the border for second product?

Comment: please read my edit. if you scroll the css down you would see something like this `.first > grid-item a` instead of `first`write `product`. i have do that, that you can image how selectors will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Inside your CSS file Add this: `border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
margin-right: 5px;` in the `.product { ...` and from `.grid-item {` remove `padding-left: 40px;` the last and final stye: remove `margin-bottom: 30px;` from `.coll-prod-caption {...` That should give you the exact result!